# D3 change the background color of an element based on it's data value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working with D3js and I have this project where I have to sort some data with data chart and stuff. What I want to do is colorize the charts background based on their data value.
For example, the more points a student has, the darker his chart will be.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaXzp.png) is what I want to do and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHdyr.png) is what I have.

Lets say my data array is:

```
var students =
 {"name":"John","value":"9"},
{"name":"Jack" ,"value":"10"},
{"name":"Peter","value":"3"}];
```

And this is my script.js class which I use to draw my charts:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, d3.max(students, function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
    .domain(students.map(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    }));

//make y axis to show bar names
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    //no tick marks
    .tickSize(0)
    .orient("left");

var gy = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(students)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

//append rects
bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.name);
    })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.value);
    });
```

Is there anyway I can do this, maybe by "if(students.value<=10) bar.style.backgroundcolor("red") else if(students.value <=5)bar.style.backgroundcolor("pink")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a color scale and use it to set the fill attribute for the rectangles. In the example below, I use a [sequential scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#sequential-scales) for this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      // chart data

      const data = [
        {name: 'John', value: 80},
        {name: 'Jane', value: 85},
        {name: 'Albert', value: 56},
        {name: 'Ramson', value: 90},
        {name: 'Rick', value: 70},
        {name: 'Karen', value: 30},
        {name: 'Jaden', value: 40},
        {name: 'Gustav', value: 15},
        {name: 'Nathan', value: 95},
      ].sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value));

      // dimensions and margins

      const margin = { top: 10, bottom: 30, left: 30, right: 10};

      const width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      const g = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // scales

      const x = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.15);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
          .range([height, 0]);

      const color = d3.scaleSequential()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
          .interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);

      // axis generators

      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

      // draw bars

      g.append('g')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .join('rect')
          .attr('x', d => x(d.name))
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
          .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
          .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value))
          .attr('fill', d => color(d.value));

      // draw axes

      g.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
          .call(xAxis);

      g.append('g')
          .call(yAxis);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your reply. The answer seems right but how do I get it to run with my example? I mean, which part do I have to copy here and paste on my code to make it work? Since I am new to all this D3 data visualizing It is kind of hard for me to understand all of the code. Can you please tell me which part is for coloring ? I tried copying this

      `const color = d3.scaleSequential()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
          .interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);`
But it didn't really do anything, maybe i pasted it on the wrong order or idk :(

Comment: The key parts are creating the color scale and then using the color scale to set the fill attribute for the rectangles: `.attr('fill', d => color(d.value))`. The fill attribute sets the color of the rect. `color` is a function, where the input is a student's value and the output is a color. The rest of the code that I've provided is very similar to the code that you have. One thing to note is that my answer is for more modern versions of D3 (versions 5-7). It looks like your code is using version 3, which has some big differences. I'd recommend using a more recent version. It will be easier.

Comment: I created an array instead, with all my desired colors that I wanted to use and then I added
   
`.attr("fill", function(d,i) { return aColor[i]; });`    to my rect and it's working properly. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Dan, can I ask you one more question please? I'm having troubles loading real data on my bar and my pie chart. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191947/d3-js-how-to-merge-my-real-data-into-a-pie-chart) question I asked yesterday. I want to display my real data that I retrieve from database and make my bar chart dynamic not just static with some data in an array. Can you answer that please?